# PHP Session Start Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write | Following Extensive Troubleshooting

Tags: php, apache, session, caching, fatal-error

## Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write on line 3

I've looked extensively for an answer to my specific situation with no progress.  Please review what I've already tried and I've included my VPS global php.ini file. No php.ini files exist within the website root.

`<?php`
`session_start();`
`?>`
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html>`

I have no idea how that's possible.  Please check out what I've already done to try to solve the problem.

Problem originated when I was unable to pass variables to another page using 
`$_SESSION['$example']` variables with no luck.  But I'll worry about that next.

## VPS System Specs Currently (Servers/Networks Are Not My Strong Area)

***Apache 3 on CentOS 6.8***

- Default PHP Version | 5
- PHP 5 Handler | suPHP
- Apache suEXEC | off
- Apache Ruid2 | off
- Default PHP Version (.php files) | 5
- PHP 5 Handler    | suPHP

## Attempted Solutions

### Disabled .htaccess

.htaccess contains 
`***suPHP_ConfigPath /***`
`Header append Vary User-Agent`

Prior to disabling:

- Removed All 301 Rewrite Rules as I've read they interfere with
  sessions
- Disabled Error Documents

### Ensure No Whitespaces Following ***session_start();***

### Caching

- Turned off all caching through WHM (that I'm aware of)
- Tested both Firefox and Chrome before and after clearing history/cookies/cache/etc
- Deleted CloudFlare service  for this domain

## Additional Information

I Don't have a php.ini file since I use a VPS (in case anyone was wondering)

***I use php on almost every other page.***

Here is an example of the first few lines of another page.

`<?php`
`session_start();`
`$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`
`//Version 1.75`

The above code is just the first few lines but the page executes fine without issue.  It should be noted that this is a redirect page following a PayPal payment to my website.  This issue is recent and previously it has worked fine.

It should also be noted that I use `session_write_close():` `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();` on appropriate pages to unset all `$_SESSION` variables and terminate sessions.

Below is a link to the php.ini file as text if that helps.  The domain contained in the link is not the domain with the issue.  I'm not attempting to be "shifty" about the domain with the issue, I just don't want people using the service when it's not working properly.

[Global PHP INI File As Text Document](http://louisvillewebsitebuilder.com/phpconfig.txt)

***Anyone who solves this, I owe you!***

-Andrew

Comment: PHP's engine won't try to evaluate variables in single quotes unless escaped and concatenated. Unless you have a `$_SESSION` variable as the string `$example` then it wouldn't return anything. That's not the same as `$_SESSION[$example]` or `$_SESSION["{$example}"]` or `$_SESSION["$example"]` in which that variable would be rendered.

Comment: Seriously, you showed a lot of stuff but __no__ related code? What do you expect from us?

Comment: Two entries in the php.ini stand out, `session.name =` and `session.cookie_domain =` - both with no value assigned. PHP usually has sensible defaults for its settings if they are not overwritten by php.ini or other means of config, but I don't know what happens if an empty value is assigned explicitly. I'd try and at least set them at runtime using the according functions before calling session_start.

Comment: @CBroe I did set the session.name.  Thank you for that.  I assume I should change it to something other than the default `PHPSESSID`?  I;m not sure what to set as the cookie domain since I run multiple domains on the server or is that not relevant?

Comment: @u_mulder The server's php.ini file was the relevant code which was listed at the bottom in a link if you read that far.  The changes I made there fixed the issue.

Comment: @Blake The `$_SESSION` variables I use are strings in this case (luckily).  I was not aware of that.  For example, my standard structure is `$number = $_SESSION['$num']`    I'm lucky they all happen to be strings.  I'll open another query following some research. I have not seen a thought-out explanation with examples of proper `$_SESSION` variable usage.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved Accidentally

I solved the issues, but still don't know what was causing the Fatal Error

- Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write on line 3
- `$_SESSION` variables didn't pass between pages.

I solved both the Fatal Error issue and the `$_SESSION` variables problem by doing one thing. For some, this may be standard procedure, but I am self-taught and this did not occur to me.  I was making changes to the PHP advanced configuration in WHM and never did not see any changes as a result.

I was banging my head against the wall for two days trying every solution I read in the forums.

### Apache Server Restart

***I never restarted my Apache Server during this time, both issues were resolved.***

***While this solution may seem rudimentary or common practice for some, it's easy to overlook.  I read at least 30 different forum posts on Stack Overflow and other sites.  Not one suggested an Apache Restart as a method to check.***

### PHP Configuration

I changed my PHP configuration as listed below and my sessions variables were passing.

`session.use_cookies = 1`
`session.use_only_cookies = 1`
`session.use_trans_sid = 0`

Thank you for everyone who took the time to look at this.

Sincerely, *Andrew*